# What are the best ways to connect a Raspberry Pi and an Android device without the availability of Wi-Fi?

Tags: camera, android

I am using a Raspberry Pi as the main controller for a project that will be constantly filming a video. My goal is for the Pi to stream the footage in real time to an Android device (using an app that I will develop myself). However, this camera will nearly always be used in a location where Wi-Fi access is not available. Ruling out the possibility of a standard Internet connection, what are the best ways to stream this footage to the device in real time without spending a lot of extra money?

Answer (score 1):

You are using and android phone. So create a wifi hotspot on the phone, then connect the raspberry you phone's hotspot. Or you can create a hotspot on the raspberry pi itself.
Try out this link [Turn a RaspBerryPi 3 into a WiFi router-hotspot](https://medium.com/@edoardo849/turn-a-raspberrypi-3-into-a-wifi-router-hotspot-41b03500080e)

Comment: Hello! The question was explicitly asked not to use wifi. Please read the headline.

Comment: @Ingo You don't need internet access to create and use a wifi hotspot (ie., an isolated WLAN); the question does not explicitly say wifi cannot be used, it says, "a location where Wi-Fi access is *not available*", where "Wi-Fi" is colloquial for *internet access*.  To be clear: There is some confusion about the difference between wifi (a wireless networking protocol) and the internet.  Either one could exist exactly as it does today even if the other one did not ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possilbe to send video over radio or bluetooth if for some reason you don't want to use wifi for some reason. Also do you mean no Internet access or not using Wi-Fi because those two are very different.

Comment: I don't believe that bluetooth is fast enough for real time video. And how do you want to use radio on the Android device?

Comment: possible not easy or preferred should be only used if litterely no other way